# Windows Batch Programming

Tags: batch-file, robocopy, s-maxage

I have some files that are automatically generated by an external sources into a local machine each day.
I have batch script, which moves the data from that source folder into a destination folder.
So i would like to move the files using time and date. But the robocopy command only accepts date.
Please see the script below

```
robocopy \\IP\f$\EMAILMT\202 C:\IntellinxServices\Queues\SwiftGen\MT202 *.rje /MAXAGE:%NEWDATE%
```

Comment: Edit your question to describe what is it that you need to do - include paths, filetypes and examples if you want some suggestions that will actually work.

Comment: Are you looking to move files with timestamps less then 1 day?

Comment: i want to move files using the robocopy command, to pick files generated on a previous day and at a particular time

Comment: robocopy doesn't have minute granularity.  XXcopy does.

Comment: xxcopy?? i have tried using xcopy. what options would be passed?

Comment: XXcopy isnt recognized as a command.

Comment: [XXCOPY](http://www.xxcopy.com/) is a third-party utility.